# iptables - percentage sign followed by an i (%i)

Tags: linux, iptables, network-interface, wireguard

I have this iptables rule that comes with my autogenerated wireguard config as a `postup` rule. I tried to figure out each step of the rule. But neither the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html#OPTIONS) or a search engine would tell me what the `%i` means, behind the `-o/--out-interface` option. I guess it's a lookup or wildcard for the interface name.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything to iptables. It comes from wg-quick, which replaces each `%i` in a PostUp command with the actual WireGuard interface name currently being configured.